# To Highlight a word/text and drag to other text box in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, highlight, drag

Is it possible to highlight a word or text in One text box and be able to drag the highlighted(selected) text or word to other text from a complete sentence that would be present in the first text box in React?

I have seen a package but that's for React Native not for the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use React-DnD and use a Drag and Drop Operation,
https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview

You have to implement the same with text so that you can Drag and Drop them

```
function collect(connect, monitor) {
  return {
    highlighted: monitor.canDrop(),
    hovered: monitor.isOver(),
    connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget()
  }
}
```